# Similar record types in a list/array in purescript

Tags: purescript

Is there any way to do something like

```
first = {x:0}
second = {x:1,y:1}
both = [first, second]
```

such that `both` is inferred as `{x::Int | r}` or something like that?

I've tried a few things:

```
[{x:3}] :: Array(forall r. {x::Int|r})    -- nope

test = Nil :: List(forall r. {x::Int|r})
{x:1} : test                              -- nope

type X r = {x::Int | r}
test = Nil :: List(X)              -- nope
test = Nil :: List(X())
{x:1} : test
{x:1, y:1} : test                  -- nope
```

Everything I can think of seems to tell me that combining records like this into a collection is not supported.  Kind of like, a function can be polymorphic but a list cannot.  Is that the correct interpretation?  It reminds me a bit of the F# "value restriction" problem, though I thought that was just because of CLR  restrictions whereas JS should not have that issue.  But maybe it's unrelated.

Is there any way to declare the list/array to support this?

Comment: Turns out typescript supports this well, and the type of `[{x:0},{x:1,y:'a'}]` is just `[{x:int} | {x:int, y:char}]`, and it only allows you to append those types, and recognizes you can always get an `x` out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is "[*existential types*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Existential_type)", and PureScript just doesn't support those at the syntax level the way Haskell does. But you can roll your own :-)

**One way to go** is "data abstraction" - i.e. encode the data in terms of operations you'll want to perform on it. For example, let's say you'll want to get the value of `x` out of them at some point. In that case, make an array of these:

```
type RecordRep = Unit -> Int

toRecordRep :: forall r. { x :: Int | r } -> RecordRep
toRecordRep {x} _ = x

-- Construct the array using `toRecordRep`
test :: Array RecordRep
test = [ toRecordRep {x:1}, toRecordRep {x:1, y:1} ]

-- Later use the operation
allTheXs :: Array Int
allTheXs = test <#> \r -> r unit
```

If you have multiple such operations, you can always make a record of them:

```
type RecordRep = 
    { getX :: Unit -> Int
    , show :: Unit -> String
    , toJavaScript :: Unit -> Foreign.Object
    }

toRecordRep r = 
    { getX: const r.x
    , show: const $ show r.x
    , toJavaScript: const $ unsafeCoerce r
    }
```

(note the `Unit` arguments in every function - they're there for the laziness, assuming each operation could be expensive)

**But if you really need the type machinery**, you can do what I call "poor man's existential type". If you look closely, existential types are nothing more than "deferred" type checks - deferred to the point where you'll need to see the type. And what's a mechanism to defer something in an ML language? That's right - a function! :-)

```
 newtype RecordRep = RecordRep (forall a. (forall r. {x::Int|r} -> a) -> a)

 toRecordRep :: forall r. {x::Int|r} -> RecordRep
 toRecordRep r = RecordRep \f -> f r

 test :: Array RecordRep
 test = [toRecordRep {x:1}, toRecordRep {x:1, y:1}]

 allTheXs = test <#> \(RecordRep r) -> r _.x
```

The way this works is that `RecordRep` wraps a function, which takes another function, which is polymorphic in `r` - that is, if you're looking at a `RecordRep`, you must be prepared to give it a function that can work with any `r`. `toRecordRep` wraps the record in such a way that its precise type is not visible on the outside, but it will be used to instantiate the generic function, which you will eventually provide. In my example such function is `_.x`.

Note, however, that herein lies the problem: the row `r` is literally not known when you get to work with an element of the array, so you can't do anything with it. Like, at all. All you can do is get the `x` field, because its existence is hardcoded in the signatures, but besides the `x` - you just don't know. And that's by design: if you want to put *anything* into the array, you must be prepared to get *anything* out of it.

Now, if you do want to do something with the values after all, you'll have to explain that by constraining `r`, for example:

```
newtype RecordRep = RecordRep (forall a. (forall r. Show {x::Int|r} => {x::Int|r} -> a) -> a)

toRecordRep :: forall r. Show {x::Int|r} => {x::Int|r} -> RecordRep
toRecordRep r = RecordRep \f -> f r

test :: Array RecordRep
test = [toRecordRep {x:1}, toRecordRep {x:1, y:1}]

showAll = test <#> \(RecordRep r) -> r show
```

Passing the `show` function like this works, because we have constrained the row `r` in such a way that `Show {x::Int|r}` must exist, and therefore, applying `show` to `{x::Int|r}` must work. Repeat for your own type classes as needed.

**And here's the interesting part**: since type classes are implemented as dictionaries of functions, the two options described above are actually equivalent - in both cases you end up passing around a dictionary of functions, only in the first case it's explicit, but in the second case the compiler does it for you.

Incidentally, this is how Haskell language support for this works as well.

Comment: That's interesting, you hit on exactly what I'm investigating.  If classes and sets of functions are equivalent, is there a need for classes at all?  i.e. instead of defining/implementing class Show, couldn't there be functions that takes objects of various types and append `.show()` function to them?  Of course then you'd need the ability to attach new fields to a record non-reflectively, which ps doesn't have.

Comment: Classes differ from explicit function dictionaries in that the compiler takes care of passing them around for you. Without type classes most functions would have extra parameters attached to them, which would be very awkward to use and make overloaded operators (e.g. `<$>` or `>>=`) impossible. Personally I'm not a big fan of that approach, but it's a thing people have explored a lot. Check out [this article](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/05/scrap-your-type-classes.html) for example.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about that one. Though I think there might be a way that combines the advantages of both, but requiring a new language. Still plotting.

Comment: To follow up, I got stuck on the language I was plotting. Anyway, turns out typescript supports this well, and the type of `[{x:0},{x:1,y:'a'}]` is just `[{x:int} | {x:int, y:char}]`, and it only allows you to append those types, and recognizes you can always get an `x` out.

Answer (score 3):

Folloing @FyodorSoikin answer based on "existential types" and what we can find in `purescript-exists` we can provide yet another solution.
Finally we will be able to build an `Array` of records which will be "isomorphic" to:

```hs
exists tail. Array { x :: Int | tail }
```

Let's start with type constructor which can be used to existentially quantify over a row type (type of kind `#Type`). We are not able to use `Exists` from `purescript-exists` here because PureScript has no kind polymorphism and original `Exists` is parameterized over `Type`.

```hs
newtype Exists f = Exists (forall a. f (a :: #Type))
```

We can follow and reimplement (`<Ctrl-c><Ctrl-v>` ;-)) definitions from [`Data.Exists`](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-exists/blob/v4.0.0/src/Data/Exists.purs) and build a set of tools to work with such `Exists` values:

```hs
module Main where

import Prelude

import Unsafe.Coerce (unsafeCoerce)
import Data.Newtype (class Newtype, unwrap)

newtype Exists f = Exists (forall a. f (a :: #Type)) 

mkExists :: forall f a. f a -> Exists f
mkExists r = Exists (unsafeCoerce r :: forall a. f a)

runExists :: forall b f. (forall a. f a -> b) -> Exists f -> b
runExists g (Exists f) = g f
```

Using them we get the ability to build an `Array` of `Records` with "any" tail but we have to wrap any such a record type in a `newtype` before:

```hs
newtype R t = R { x :: Int | t }
derive instance newtypeRec :: Newtype (R t) _
```

Now we can build an `Array` using `mkExists`:

```
arr :: Array (Exists R)
arr = [ mkExists (R { x: 8, y : "test"}), mkExists (R { x: 9, z: 10}) ]
```

and process values using `runExists`:

```
x :: Array [ Int ]
x = map (runExists (unwrap >>> _.x)) arr
```

Comment: The problem with `purescript-exists` is, you can't constrain the type. If the type needed to be constrained (e.g. like `Show` in my answer), the constraint would have to be baked into the definition of `Exists`, which pretty much defeats the idea of it being a reusable library. And this is _in addition_ to the other problem of it not being kind-polymorphic, which you had to work around with copy-paste.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understands your comment in this context @FyodorSoikin. 

* In original question @DaxFohl asked how to create an collection of records which share some known fields which is clearly done in my answer. We don't have to drag any constraint with this representation as we have direct access to known values.

* The Lack of kind polymorphism is not a big problem because `Exists` has to be provided once per kind  (so for example we now can reuse this `Exists` for every type which is parametrized over row).

Comment: If the OP only cared about the value of the `x` field, then he could just make an array of those values - there would be no need to make the array heterogenous, no need for `Exists` or anything else. The only reason to have a heterogenous array is to get access to the specific types of elements later in one way or another, and `Exists` does not do that.

Comment: I think that in general you are right but there are other possible reasons to build such an array like avoiding coping (when large parts of records are common) or debugging purposes and probably many others. Who knows what the original intent of OP was - the question was strictly about building an array ;-) Regarding `Exists` I'm finding it really useful for modeling `GADTs` but this is another topic I think...