# Unify record types with overlapping fields

Tags: purescript

I have the following code:

```
workWithImportantField :: forall fields. { importantField :: Int | fields } -> Input
workWithImportantField = ...

workWithImportantField $ 
maybe { importantField: 1 } identity (Just { importantField: 1, fieldIDontCareAbout: "whatever" })
```

This doesn't compile because the first record doesn't have the `fieldIDontCareAbout`. However, I'm perfectly fine if it unifies into `forall fields. { importantField :: Int | fields }` so it gets passed into `workWithImportantField`. How would I go about doing that?

I've tried adding type annotations to various places (first record, second record, the whole expression) without success. I can always replace `identity` with `unsafeCoerce`, but I would like a type-safe solution. I can also manually pick out the fields I need by replacing `identity` with `\{ importantField } -> { importantField }`, but that doesn't look nice.

Comment: I think that in theory you can use something like `Exists` (from _purescript-exists_) but  dedicated to records (like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53289906/194614). The question is if you really want to - maybe it is just better to use a "getter" like `_.importantField` instead of `identity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `identity` with `pick` found at [Record.Extra](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-record-extra/3.0.1/docs/Record.Extra#v:pick) "throws away" `fieldIDontCareAbout` from the second record so the types unify.

Comment: I think that one important detail is that you should change the question if that is the correct answer - you are not getting records which are polymorphic on the tail by using `pick` - you are building up a new records with a concrete subset of fields from there like `{ importantField :: Int }`. With the solution like _purescript-exists_ you can "forget" a part of the record without constructing a new value, but like I suggested it is in general it is probably a bad idea ;-)

Comment: I understand the question might be poorly worded since I was not sure what I was looking for, but I would rather leave it as is so that others who also don't quite know what they're looking for might find this more easily.

Comment: Cool. I agree that you have found a better solution than using existentials (which is usually a heavy hammer) but I think that the response should reflect that flow of thought. Would you be so kind and add some info about that? Of course I can help to compose this info if you don't have time :-)